# SQL - How to reset Rank function based on time period?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am trying to model a user journey and I have the following table called interactions:

| uid | date | touchpoint | transaction |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | 2021-01-01 | mail | 0 |
| 1234 | 2021-01-02 | call | 0 |
| 1234 | 2021-01-10 | call | 1 |
| 4567 | 2021-01-11 | cnh1 | 1 |
| 4567 | 2021-01-12 | mail | 0 |

Considering a the journey is all touch points a user interacts with in a 3 days window (resetting after 3 days without a new touch point) I would need the following result:

| uid | path | transaction |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | mail > call | 0 |
| 1234 | call | 1 |
| 4567 | cnh1 | 1 |
| 4567 | cnh1 > mail | 0 |

Here is what I have so far.

```
SELECT 
  uid,
  STRING_AGG(touchpoint, ">") OVER (PARTITION BY uid ORDER BY UNIX_SECONDS(TIMESTAMP_SECONDS(interactionTime)) RANGE BETWEEN 172800 PRECEDING AND 0 PRECEDING AS path,
transaction
FROM Interactions
```

the problem is that I get one row for every step like

```
touchpoint 1
touchpoint 1 > touchpoint 2
touchpoint 2 > touchpoint 2 > touchpoint 3
```

...

I believe I need to have a journey ID and get the longest path per journey, but I am not sure how to do this.

Comment: So what results do you want?  How do you define a "journey", if not by the three day limit you have in the question?

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm . . . I'm thinking a brute force approach might be best.  That would be to ignore a given row when the next row contains that row:

```
SELECT i.*
FROM (SELECT i.*,
             LEAD(path) OVER (PARTITION BY uid ORDER BY interactionTime) as next_path
      FROM (SELECT uid, interactionTime,
                   STRING_AGG(touchpoint, '>') OVER (
                       PARTITION BY uid
                       ORDER BY UNIX_SECONDS(TIMESTAMP_SECONDS(interactionTime)) 
                       RANGE BETWEEN 172800 PRECEDING AND 0 PRECEDING
                      ) AS path,
                   transaction
              FROM Interactions
             ) i
    ) i
WHERE next_path NOT LIKE CONCAT(path, '>%');
```